# How do I measure the % of processor time and total memory consumed by a workflow?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to measure the amount of processor time & total memory used to execute a workflow.

This is my setup:

I have a ASP.NET app that invokes a WCF service.

The WCF service executes few methods and then calls the workflow associated with it by using the Run method of the WorkflowApplication class.

I have been using the performance counters in the “Process” category to get data on the % of Processor time, Total Memory used.

As you’d imagine, because it is the web service that executes the workflow, all workflows are running under the w3wp process.

How do I go about capturing the performance counter information for each workflow rather than the process?

Also I’d appreciate any pointers / comments on why this approach (of capturing processor time and memory used per workflow) itself is unnecessary :)

Note: I don’t want to write code inside the Activity using System.GC namespace to get a count of total bytes that are used.

Comment: What about using System.GC inside a tracking participant? There are ways of getting the executed activity from tracking record. I'm not experienced with traCing, could it be useful? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462013.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are perfmon counters about the number of workflow executing but not about the actual CPU and memory usage. Often workflows are long running and are idle and persisted to disk most of the time so there is little point in tracking CPU/Memory usage. That said, there are times when they are busy and are doing things and you could easily have a memory leak of sorts there that causes problems after some time.

In general I tend to prefer Workflow Services and in that case I can put them in a separate app pool in IIS so I can track CPU/Memory usages for that specific app pool. But as you are using an WorkflowApplication that is not an option for you and you would have to resort to a profiler like the [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). Great for development use but not so good for monitoring production apps. In that case you would need to start adding instrumentation to you own activities.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest way to do it would be running each activity in a separated `System.Diagnostic.Process`

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (
    "MyWorkflowApplication.exe", 
    "c:/My workflow service.xaml"
);

long memory = process.PagedMemorySize64;
TimeSpan processorTime = process.TotalProcessorTime;
```